# Serilog and ExpandoObject

Tags: json, serilog, expandoobject

If I have ExpandoObject like this:

```
dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
d.x = "a";
d.y = "b";
```

and log it with Serilog to RollingFile using JsonFormatter like this:

```
_logger.Debug("{@d}", d);
```

it will be serialised to json like this:

```
[{"_typeTag":"KeyValuePair`2","Key":"x","Value":"a"},{"_typeTag":"KeyValuePair`2","Key":"y","Value":"b"}]
```

If I use Newtonsoft.Json to serialise the same ExpandoObject like this:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d)
```

I will get this:

```
{"x":"a","y":"b"}
```

How can I make Serilog produce the same json as Newtonsoft.Json does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding:

```
.Destructure.ByTransforming<ExpandoObject>(e => new Dictionary<string,object>(e))
```

to your `LoggerConfiguration` should do it.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, this solved the RollingFile issue. Is there also a way to fix how this looks in Console? I get `{["x"]="a", ["y"]="b"}`, preferably there should be no square brackets around the keys.

Comment: Also can you please help me with something else. If I deserialise a json string `"{\"x\":\"a\",\"y\":\"b\"}"` with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()`, the resulting object logs as `[[[]],[[]]]`. I obviously expect `{"x":"a","y":"b"}`

Comment: For the console, updating to the latest _Serilog.Sinks.Console_ and using its default output template should do it (for the file, _Serilog.Formatting.Compact_ has some better JSON formatters, BTW). To log JSON.NET objects, see https://github.com/destructurama/json-net.

Comment: Nicholas thank you very much! With your help I have now resolved all my formatting issues.